# Is $H^*(G;M)$ finitely generated?

Tags: group-cohomology

Let $G$ a finite abelian group and $M$ a finitely generated G-module.

We consider the cohomology module $H^*(G;M)$, which is a $H^*(G;\mathbb{Z})$-module with the cup-product.

Is always $H^*(G;M)$ finitely generated? Or, at least, is there any condition which on $M$ or $G$ which ensures it?

Comment: "abelian group et $M$"?? Otherwise, see [here](http://www.math.ucla.edu/~rouquier/papers/cohomology.pdf).

Comment: @DietrichBurde: I've passed too much time in France! Anyway, thank you very much for your answer, it is exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: This follows out of tthe proof of finite generation of the cohomology of $G$ done by Evens, if II recall correctly. See the 2nd volume of Benson's book on cohomology and representations.

Comment: (If $G$ is finite abelian, then it is a direct product of cyclic groups, and $M$ is a direct sum of modules one for each factor of that decomposition. A Künneth formula applies and this reduces your special case to the the situation in which $G$ is cyclic, and there you can surely compute directly that $H^*(G,M)$ is generated by its degrees $\leq 2$)

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez: In general $H^*(G,M)$ is not generated by $\leq 2$ degrees, there are conterexamples for this, as $G=(Z/2Z)^2$ and $M=\Omega^3(Z)$

Comment: @user84976, that group is not cyclic, though.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez, but $M$ is not a direct sum of modules over cyclic groups

Comment: I did not say it is. :-/

Comment: You said "$M$ is a direct sum of modules one for each factor of that decomposition"